# Android: LogCat points to wrong class

Tags: android, logcat

Let's say you have 2 projects: Egg and Spam, with Spam being a clone of Egg that you're working on. You make some changes to a class in Spam, run it and it crashes. You look at LogCat and it's telling you that line 40 of class DBAdapter in Spam has some errors in it. You tell LogCat to jump to that line, but instead it takes you to line 40 of class DBAdapter in Egg.
Would anyone know how this sort of thing is fixed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, eclipse (or LogCat) mixes them up if the source files are the same and the project you are currently working on is alphabetically lower (Your project "SPAM" and "EGG"). Since EGG shows up first , then SPAM that's why it is going to the source of EGG.

Easy solution, just close EGG Project for a while, then click on LogCat to jump to that line. It will surely point correctly in SPAM Project. cheers